# How to change two different date format into single date format in excel

Tags: excel, date

I have a different date format(YYYY.MM.DD and MM/DD/YYYY) in my date column in Excel. As a final result, I want one date format ie MM/DD/YYYY. What is the easiest way to achieve it?

Here is an image of my data.on Right-click and Format cell it looks like below.

[image]

The final output I want to like this. .I have tried Text to Columns option as well but it didn't work. Please help

[image]

Comment: You'll have to write a formula that detects if the string in the cell is formatted with periods or slashes and check if the first number has four digits, then convert it to a date with something like `=DATE(LEFT(A2,4),MID(A2,6,2),RIGHT(A2,2))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in **A2**, in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),A2,DATE(LEFT(A2,4),MID(A2,6,2),RIGHT(A2,2)))
```

and apply your format to **B2**.

Then copy **B2** downward:

[image]

The formula converts any text values in column **A** into true Excel dates in column **B**.

Comment: Or: `=IF(ISNUMBER(--A2),--A2,--SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","-"))` too similar to yours to post a new answer.

Comment: Hi  Gary, Though it looks working fine for slash values for dot values it's subtracting 1 from the year part as well as Month part is also not correct.Like this
original  2000.06.19  After applying formula 12/19/1999
Formula-=IF(ISNUMBER(A2);A2;DATE(LEFT(A2;4);MID(A2;5;2);RIGHT(A2;2)))

Comment: @Yogeeyadav  The MID() part should be **MID(A2;6;2)**  I will fix the Picture.

Comment: Hi @Gary'sStudent.Thank you. It looks good now.